# How to select multiple elements in RadEditor in ie11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, internet-explorer-11, radeditor

I am working on an application based on ASP.NET, running in IE11.

One part of the application makes use of (Telerik) `RadEditor` to create a layout of several items. I am trying to implement a feature that allows a user to select multiple elements and then align them either vertically or horizontally. I've been told that this feature used to work sometime in the past, but stopped working when **IE** upgraded either from 9 to 10, or 10 to 11.

I can select (selection border shows up on all selected elements) multiple elements in the page (in the (Telerik) `RadEditor` content space) by holding control+clicking. My problem is that the editor can't find all the selected elements, but rather returns the first one.

Relevant (Javascript) code is:

```
var editor = $find("RadEditor1");
var theSelectionObject = editor.getSelection();
var tempElem = editor.getSelectedElement();
```

Both `theSelectionObject` and `tempElem` are references to a single object. How can I get a collection of ALL selected elements or otherwise determine which elements are selected to use in later code?

Comment: I think this is what you need: https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/enable-multiple-css-class-selection  If you can't make it work then let me know and I will try to help you implement it.

Comment: Looking over that code you linked, I don't think it is trying to solve the same problem I am, but I am trying it. When I choose the new option in my toolbar I get a 404 error. Where am I supposed to put the CssExtender.aspx file? The url currently requested is "/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/ToFlexWYSIWYGProvider09/Toolbars/CssExtender.aspx", but I can't find that in my project.

Comment: CssExtender.aspx is the editor helper page you have to create and modify the location according to where you put it. This may be more than what you need.  I think you can try to use RadEditor.getSelectedElement() rather than .getSelection().

Comment: @DaniDev I made the CssExtender.aspx file, it's sitting in a directory next to the file I am loading it from. I don't understand where or how to include it though. I tried using getSelectedElement() and it only returns a single element. I am trying to get multiple elements at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is what you are trying to do. It appears that the Telerik provided functions may not be able to do that for you. But the the good news is that you can write your own JavaScript library function that will get all the selected elements in you editor. The example in discussion may help you as it shows how to implement an editor helper interface selecting multiple elements by CSS class

Answer (score 0):

The IE version of the browser's execCommand method offers a **MultipleSelection** option which allows for the selection of more than one site selectable element at a time when the user holds down the SHIFT or CTRL keys. You can find more info at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/hh801232(v%3dvs.85)#multipleselection](http://MultipleSelection%20Allows%20for%20the%20selection%20of%20more%20than%20one%20site%20selectable%20element%20at%20a%20time%20when%20the%20user%20holds%20down%20the%20SHIFT%20or%20CTRL%20keys.)

To fire this method via the RadEditor API do:

```
editor.get_document().execCommand('MultipleSelection', true, true);
```